# ffmpeg limit number of images converted to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Is it possible to instruct ffmpeg to combine a limited range of images together?

Lets say there is a folder of 1000 images named `img_0001.jpg` to `img_1000.jpg` and I only wanted to combine `img_0250.jpg` through `img_0750.jpg`.

The `-start_number` option specifies a starting point but from there it will run until the end of the sequence:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 250 -i img_%4d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 output.mp4
```

Is there a way of specify a `-stop_number` or total number of frames to run for?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`-frames:v`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options):

```
ffmpeg -i img_%4d.jpg -frames:v 500 output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks LordNeckbeard. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: NOTE: you should use `-frames:v` since `-vframes` is obsolete now

Comment: @incBrain I see no deprecation messages in a build from the current git master branch, and no recent commits in the git log indicating any changes to the status.

Comment: @llogan from https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options *This is an obsolete alias for -frames:v, which you should use instead.* Or is the doc not up to date? This also can be the case. Not sure

Comment: @incBrain It doesn't mean someone is about to kill `-vframes` despite that ominous sounding sentence. There is no reason to. In reality it makes no difference which option users use. Regardless, I'll update the old answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `-t` option specifies the length of the output in either seconds or hh.mm.ss[.xxx] format (x=milliseconds)
Alternatively the `-to` option sets the stop time, again in seconds or hh.mm.ss[.xxx] format

These are in the output options, rather than the input options btw.

More info at the [ffmpeg documentation page](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options), strangely enough.

Comment: I had been thinking that I needed an input option but restricting the output could do the equivalent. I will test and report back.

Comment: While writing the answer I was wondering why it's an output option rather than an input one. It's logical either way though.

Comment: `-t` can also be used as an input option although this is currently undocumented.